# BarcodeDetector not working on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, electron, macos-ventura

My Electron app works fine on macOS Monterey.

On Ventura, following code doesn’t throw error but `detectedBarcodes` is always empty.

```js
const barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector({ formats: ["qr_code"] })
const detectedBarcodes = await barcodeDetector.detect(imageData)
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: Created [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/36242) on Electron repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same problem in some non-Electron code, and I just checked one of the online demos and that also stopped working on Chrome.

I filed an issue there ...

https://github.com/xulihang/barcode-detection-api-demo/issues/1